# Rspec rubocop error `prefer using verifying doubles over normal doubles`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubocop

I've a RSpec test

```
let(:mail_instance) { double(deliver_later: nil) }

before do
  allow(ConfirmationMailer).to receive(:send_email).and_return(mail_instance)
  allow(mail_instance).to receive(:deliver_later)
end

it 'calls mailer, and delivers the mail' do
  call_endpoint
  expect(mail_instance).to have_received(:deliver_later)
end
```

And it works well but I've got rubocop error - `prefer using verifying doubles over normal doubles`. According to docs https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.7.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/VerifiedDoubles I should use `instance_double` instead but if I change it my specs will we falls with an error:

> ArgumentError:
>          Module or String expected, got {:deliver_later=>nil}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass the class you're stubbing to the `instance_double`:

```
let(:mail_instance) { instance_double(ActionMailer::MessageDelivery, deliver_later: nil) }
```

Comment: That's a "correct" way to mock them, and I think that it's important to know the difference between doubles and doubles, DO NOT write code for rubocop I guess that idea behind it's  to learn about every rule.

Answer (score 10):

The idea it's that you should use `instance_double`, but I guess that it's important to understand why Rubocop says that.

The main difference between `doubles` and `instance_doubles` is
If we try to use/call a method which is NOT implemented by the class of the mocked instance, it will raise an exception. If we decide to use mock objects in our tests, instance_doubles provides us with a bit more confidence in our tests than if we were using spies or regular doubles.

So if in the future someone rename or delete that method, if you use double you probably never know and your will pass, but if you use instance_doubles you will be notified.

Obiously there is a slightly performance trade-off between both, but in 99% of the time for me it's better to use `instance_doubles`

Comment: When would you use doubles?

Comment: I don't use doubles.

Comment: @Sasha When the object dynamically turn attributes into methods, we will have to use doubles instead of instance doubles